# Term for "wiggly argument"?

Tags: word-choice

What kind of adjective would you use for an argument that doesn't stand on a very firm ground?

It came to my mind "wiggly argument" (like it wiggles) but apparently that term is not used.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Logical arguments are rarely described with video metaphors (though perhaps that might be a good strategy for some). Note that "on firm ground" is itself a metaphor, since arguments are not people or buildings and therefore can't "stand", and no ground of any firmness is involved.

Comment: you might call it "shaky" but not "wiggly"

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Why was this closed? I did include research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might call it [**shaky**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shaky)

> uncertain or questionable. "Your arguments are very shaky"
> (Collins Dictionary, under "in British English)

> not firm, substantial, or secure; weak, unsound, or unsteady, as a structure, belief, etc. (Collins Dictionary, under "in American English")

It can have the same meaning as "unsound" (see [dubious's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/590026/369152)), but it is similar to the word you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the definition of "*[soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness)*"

> an argument is **sound** if it is both valid in form and its premises are true.

You could then say "*unsound argument*".

It's very common to also say "*weak argument*".